# Where can I download midi files of videogame music?

Tags: midi

I'm interested in creating remixes of music from video games such as Final Fantasy. I understand that MIDI files exist of this music and can be an excellent reference since they spell out every note, and I was curious if there was a reliable site or archive that offered them for download.

I guess scores could work also, but I'm really new to them.

Comment: Meta discussion [here](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/199/questions-about-where-to-find-resources-on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use [VGMusic](http://www.vgmusic.com) and [The Midi Shrine](http://www.midishrine.com) for this kind of thing.

[HQMidi](http://www.hqmidi.com/games/index.html) also has covers of Final Fantasy theme tunes on there.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! :)
I think I found VG before, I just couldn't remember the name.